# Can one twist fibred knots and still get fibred knots?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Suppose we have a fibred knot $K$ with a fiber surface $F$ and let $c$ be an unknot disjoint from $F$ (but not homotopically trivial in the complement of $F$). Is it possible that every twist along $c$ leaves $K$ fibred with $F$ still being the fiber surface?

Comment: What do you mean by "twist along $c$"?

Comment: @MarcoGolla technically it means 'perform a $1/n$ surgery on $c$ for some non-zero integer $n$'. I imagine it as cutting the solid torus (exterior of $c$) along a meridional disc, twisting and regluing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such examples were [constructed by Morton](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=728587). He showed that one can find unknotted curves lying on fiber surfaces *with zero framing*. Twisting about them preserves fiberedness and the fact that it is a knot in $S^3$. Also, curves on the fiber can be pushed disjoint from the fiber meeting your requirement.

**Edit:** As Danny points out in the comments [John Stallings originally came up with this construction.](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/stallfib2.pdf)

Comment: I think this construction is due to Stallings (Constructions of fibred knots and links, Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics, 1978) and is called a Stallings twist. You need to require that the framing on the curve from the normal to the Seifert surface is the untwisted framing.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about that.

Comment: @IanAgol I am probably being stupid, but I can't figure something out. Stallings describes his unknot as lying in the fiber surface. So if I push it away from the surface and then do a twist, does the surface still remain to be a fiber surface?

Comment: @shestipalov: Yes, the surface will remain a fiber, because the twist acts as a Dehn twist of the monodromy of the fibration.